# what happens when an app that has in-app purchase products on it gets updated?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I suppose it's up to the programmer to keep track of IAPs after the app is updated?  Would I have to write a file to the documents folder saying the IAP was purchased, and then have the code check to see if the file's there once the app updates?  I have an app out now that has in-app purchases available, and I'm planning on releasing an update, but what will happen to users that purchased IAPs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple keeps track of in-app-purchases that your users make. You can ask Apple about the in-app-purchases for the current user in `ApplicationDidFinishLaunching`.

You can keep track of in-app-purchase status in `NSUserDefaults` or perhaps the keychain. This way you don't need to constantly query Apple. Keep in mind if the app is deleted from the device the `NSUserDefaults` will be wiped out (so the app should always ask Apple in `ApplicationDidFinishLaunching`.

[Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) are a good read.

Comment: ahh those darn apple docs.  they take so long to wade through.  ok thanks, i do keep the info stored in nsuserdefaults, but i thought maybe it didn't persist with an update because i had someone update and say they lost their IAP.  they must have deleted and reinstalled...knuckleheads...

Comment: yes I believe `NSUserDefaults` sticks around for an app upgrade. This has bitten me when testing on the device... I forget to delete the app so I can test against a fresh `NSUserDefaults`.