# Mac app In-App Purchase: restore purchases after each update?

Tags: macos, cocoa, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have a Mac app that offers In-App Purchases. After releasing an update through the Mac App Store, a number of customers contacted me complaining that their purchased feature was not available anymore.

In all cases I would have the user restore their purchases by hand via a menu that I added.

However, this leaves me wondering if this happened for all users. Shouldn't the In-App-Purchases be available in the receipt as soon as an app was updated from the App Store?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what happens when an app that has in-app purchase products on it gets updated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498679/what-happens-when-an-app-that-has-in-app-purchase-products-on-it-gets-updated)

Comment: The other question does not really say anything about the app's receipt. What is meant by "you can ask Apple about the in-app-purchases"? I'd like to know if the receipt contains the in app purchase after the app was updated.

Comment: This sounds like something you may be able to test yourself. If you get ahold of a receipt after the update, you should be able to process it to see what it contains. I work with iOS, but I'm assuming the same URL's that do receipt validation for iOS work with Mac apps? If you were to post a receipt, I could do it.